# What I need to write a program for a mobile phone

Tags: java

lets suppose its a singe phone, and I want to write a program in java, I know how to program in java, but what IDE or programs I need?

for example if I want to write a program where I write some text, and then that text is saved in the database SQL-lite for example, can you give me some links where I can download it?

For example: NOKIA, SAMSUNG etc... - that support java

Comment: What mobile?  Blackberry?  Android?  Generally speaking, you will definitely need Eclipse, but you will need a different plugin depending on what you are developing for

Comment: Depends entirely on the phone. For example, an Android phone would use Eclipse, ADT and the SDK.

Comment: What's a "singe phone"? The more effort you put into making your question clear and precise, the better the answers you'll get.

Comment: Do some googling. This is not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Go and download [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and install into your PC and start coding..

Comment: what i want to write for nokia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to check if the OS of the phone has an SDK (Source Development Kit) for Java. The ones that currently are available are for Android, Blackberry OS and Symbian.

IOS for example does not have a JRE implementation and as such you cannot code apps for it in Java. To be honest, I somehow doubt they will make one available in the future since they seem to be focusing on Objective C for their development.

After you decide which OS you want to target, you then need to download the SDK. A fast google search will give you exactly what you need.

As for IDEs, it comes down to support and personal preferences. From experience, I can only talk about Android development. Google decided to offer official support for Eclipse BUT(!!!) you can also use Netbeans (by using the netbeans android plugin) and even IntelliJ, plenty of choices.

Comment: nokia? depends on the model of the phone ans subsequently what OS it is using; the older ones have mostly Symbian and the newer ones have Windows Phone which uses the .NET framework so no Java there

Comment: so its better to use C#, but if i write a program in C# it wil be runed on the nokia phone? or how can i test it?

Comment: the `Windows Phone SDK` offers a `Windows Phone Emulator` where you can load your apps and test them before deploying to a real device. this is the link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570